# Python matplotlib 3d projection error

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to print 3d scattered plot in python. However when I use this line
`ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')` I get the following error:

```
KeyError: u'_internal.classic_mode'
```

For complete information, I am running it on macOS and my matplotlib version is 1.1.3

Comment: matplotlib is up to 2.0 now, don't know if it would help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Did you import Axes3D (note the capitalization)?

`from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`

It is not explicitly used but is required for 3d projections.